# sed for search and replace a text in xml file

Tags: xml, sed

I am struggling with sed expression.

cat sample.xml:

```
<pro path="broad" name="cd/broad" remote="bit" rev="5e2b78f768dc8dd6a7d1a1153942684993b40430" groups="app" />
```

Note: rev could also be equal to "master" or "commitid"

Expression:

```
sed -i "s/^\([[:space:]]*\)\(<pro\)\([[:space:]]\)\(path=.*\)\(rev=\)\([0-9a-f]{40}\)\([[:space:]]\)\(.*\)/\1\2\3\4\5blah\7/g" sample.xml
```

I want to change revision=5e2b78f768dc8dd6a7d1a1153942684993b40430 to rev=blah

My output should be:

```
<pro path="broad" name="cd/broad" remote="bit" rev="blah" branch="master" groups="apps" />
```

Could someone please help me fix my sed expression?

Comment: Your XML is invalid, the `rev` value should be double quoted

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried with putting the double quotes but still it doesn't work

Comment: You ask for a regex to parse your HTML. [Never parse HTML or XML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) you might meet the pony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way forward is to make use of an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed --update '//pro/@rev' --value "blah" xmlfile.xml
```

Note, since we do not have a clear picture of your full XML, this might not work.

Remark: if you want to add the `branch` attribute you can do it in a single go:

```
xmlstarlet ed --update '//pro/@rev' --value "blah" \
              --insert '//pro' --type attr --name "branch" --value "master" xmlfile.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for brief explanation and showing me a different approach to this problem :)